# python dictionary float search within range

Tags: python, search

Suppose I have some kind of dictionary structure like this (or another data structure representing the same thing.

```
d = {
  42.123231:'X',
  42.1432423:'Y',
  45.3213213:'Z',
  ..etc
}
```

I want to create a function like this:

```
f(n,d,e):
    '''Return a list with the values in dictionary d corresponding to the float n
    within (+/-) the float error term e'''
```

So if I called the function like this with the above dictionary:

```
f(42,d,2)
```

It would return

```
['X','Y']
```

However, while it is straightforward to write this function with a loop, I don't want to do something that goes through every value in the dictionary and checks it exhaustively, but I want it to take advantage of the indexed structure somehow (or a even a sorted list could be used) to make the search much faster.

Comment: Consider using a `list` and the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect#searching-sorted-lists) module.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary is a wrong data structure for this. Write a search tree.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary is a hashmap implementation. Its keys can't be compared and traversed as in search tree. So you simply can't do it using python dictionary without actually checking all keys.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries with numeric keys are usually sorted - by key values. But you may - to be on the safe side - rearrange it as OrderedDictionary - you do it once

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d_ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key =lambda i:i[0]))
```

Then filtering values is rather simple - and it will stop at the upper border

```
import itertools    
values = [val for k, val in 
          itertools.takewhile(lambda (k,v): k<upper, d_ordered.iteritems()) 
          if k > lower]
```

As I've already stated, ordering dictionary is not really necessary - but some will say that this assumption is based on the current implementation and may change in the future.